# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed , fix if element not exist

Tags: java, selenium

**How to install in my code "time loop", if program does not finish the loop for 1 min then return or read the next line?**
**How to skipp if not find element ? **
**How to skip if not load page or error page **

Comment: Maybe u need use flush() method before use close().

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly.